# Как создать список списков, в котором строки и числа с плавающей точкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не волшебник ни разу. Учусь. Делаю небольшой парсер сайта. Собираю данные из таблицы в список. Сразу преобразовываю нужные мне элементы из строк в числа с плавающей точкой. Потом хочу списки один за другим отправить в список списков.

```
def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for i, row in enumerate(soup.html.body.table.findAll("tr")):
        r_list = []
        for cell in row.findAll("td"):
            r_list.append(cell.string.strip())

        if len(r_list)>0:
            for i, x in enumerate(r_list):
                try:
                    r_list[i] = float(x)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            table.append(r_list)

        print("\n\n\t =======In tr loop r_list =========\n")
        print ('\n\t\t'.join(r_list))
    print ("\n ---- table (appended) ----- table len: ", len(table) , "\n")
```

При первом же цикле записи переменной r_list в список списков переменной table получаю:

```
     40         print("\n\n\t =======In tr loop r_list =========\n")
---> 41         print ('\n\t\t'.join(r_list))
     42 
     43     print ("\n ---- table (appended) ----- table len: ", len(table) , "\n")

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

Как можно создать список списков из чисел с плавающей точкой и строк? Спасибо.

Comment: Немного поправил формулировку. Обратите внимание, что числа с плавающей точкой и даже целые числа не являются сами по себе "десятичными". Десятичный вид - это просто человекочитаемое представление числа (целого или с плавающей точкой). Внутри машины же все хранится в двоичном виде.

Comment: Спасибо, @insolor! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не получился вывод так как `join()` хочет строку.

Сделайте так:

```
print('\n\t\t'.join(map(str, r_list)))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, @Alban! Про join почитаю подробнее. Получилось сделать списки из string и float.

Answer (score 1):

Если в списке находятся и строки, и числа, то нельзя просто к списку применить `join`, и получить строку: cначала нужно все элементы привести к строкам. В простейшем случае это можно сделать так:

```
print ('\n\t\t'.join(str(item) for item in r_list))
```

Если нужно специальное форматирование для чисел с плавающей точкой (например, нужно указать конкретное количество цифр после запятой), то для элементов типа `float` нужно будет дополнительно применить форматирование:

```
print ('\n\t\t'.join('{:.5}'.format(item) if isinstance(item, float) else str(item) for item in r_list))
```

(тут для примера ограничиваем количество выводимых цифр после запятой для чисел с плавающей точкой до 5)

Comment: там у меня список изначально только из строк состоит таким вот образом:

['72', 'г. Железнодорожный, ул. Советская, д. 34', '1978', '7 274.90', '357', 'нет данных']

Про форматирование чисел с плавающей точкой учту. Спасибо большое.